# How connect two subjobs with tUnite

Tags: talend

I'm trying to connect two "subjobs" with the object `tUnite`.

However I get an error :

```
Exception in component tHashInput_tUnite_3 (format)
java.lang.RuntimeException: The hash is not initialized : The hash must exist before you read from it
```

I think that is happening because a "subjob" finished before the other one.

It exists a way to do that or I must create two jobs?

**Current structure**

[image]

**Note:** Both `tSortRow` object (`tri` and `tSortRow_2`) have same structure.

Thank's for help!

Comment: Hi. Could you please show the part where you have a tHashInput ?

Comment: Hi! I'm not using `tHasInput`. That's why I don't understand this error.

Comment: hum that is weird.. Could you then show the whole subjob ?

Comment: @iMezouar I updated my post.

Comment: Your job looks good to me.. what is the component throwing the error ?

Comment: I think it is `tUnite_3` because the error display  `tHashInput_tUnite_3`. Then, I don't know why execution is stoped on `tUnite_2` (no green message after it).

Comment: I don't see what causes this error.. Have you at any point used a tHashInput in your job ? (sometimes a component remains even after you delete it)

Comment: No I never used `tHashInput`... Maybe that `tUnite` use `tHashInput`? Using `tUnit` to regroup two `tSortRow` is the good way? And any idea why there is no green message after `tUnite_2`?

Comment: I don't see how that could be.. I created a sample job with tUnite, and looking at the java code, I don't see any tHashInput there. Could you please look inside the source file of your job ? You can find it in your workspace > PROJECT FOLDER > process > then yourjob.item. Open it in notepad, and search for tHashInput.

Comment: Same here, I don't have any entry for `tHashInput` into `file.item`. I despair...

Comment: When I create a new job and I paste the "subjob 1", it works. Same with "subjob 2". So the problem is when I regroup both "subjob".

Comment: So I don't know why but I removed and added `tUnite_3` for the third time and it works...

Comment: I've had that happen to me before, removing and adding a component sometimes solves these weird issues ! :)

Comment: @iMezouar thanks again! ;) At least, I know it can happened.

Comment: May be you can change your job like, add first subjob data to thashoutput, and 'onSubJobOk' of that add second subjob data to another hashoutput then 'onComponentOk' of second subjob add two hashinput to read and unit data.

Answer (score -1):

Remove and then add a new tUnite.
It worked for me.